# ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2) for dual axis chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a dual axis chart where the months of the year is the x -axis which the 2 columns share and the 2 different y-axis should be the values of the different columns. The dataframe,df looks like this

```
 index    TotalEvtCount    ObservedNumEvntNam
 Mar        2670                71
 Apr        3330                55  
 Jun        7500                65
 ...
```

Here is the code:

```
t = df.index
data1=df['TotalEvtCount']
data2=df['ObservedNumEvntNam']

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

color = 'tab:red'
ax1.set_xlabel('month')
ax1.set_ylabel('EvtCount', color=color)
ax1.plot(t, data1, color=color)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis

color = 'tab:blue'
ax2.set_ylabel('NumEvntNam', color=color)  # we already handled the x-label with ax1
ax2.plot(t, data2, color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

fig.tight_layout()  # otherwise the right y-label is slightly clipped
plt.show()
```

But am getting this ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Your code displays the expected twin axis graph with Windows 10, Python 3.6, matplotlib 2.2.3, pandas 0.22. A full traceback would also be helpful. Please edit your question.

Comment: @Mr. T  I tried commenting the code from the 'ax2= ax1.twinx()' down to the end but i still got another error: **IndexError: tuple index out of range**   My version is Windows 10, Python 3.6.6.final.0, pandas: 0.20.3, matplotlib: 2.2.2

Comment: See [mcve] for what would be necessary when asking about undesired behaviour.

Comment: @Bode Ernest has given you the link you should read. Minimum requirement: A full traceback telling us in which module the mistake occurs. The environment that executes your script (Pycharm?, Anaconda?, Eclipse/PyDev?) and how you execute it, a pd dataframe that constructs sample data replicating the error. I for instance did load your sample data only to find out that your column "index" is not a data column, but indeed your index. Does your error only pop up, when you plot the twin axis? Maybe this will help in a general sense: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/